# Docker nodejs cannot open file

Tags: node.js, docker, cron, alpine-linux

I have a docker container with nodejs in it. (`node:14.11-alpine3.12`)
There is cron running, that executes .sh file with the command:
`node /home/parsecsv.js`;

Whenever cron executes this command, I get an error

```
'rror: Cannot find module '/home/parsecsv.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:893:15)
...
```

I am absolutely sure this file exists, even more, when I go to the container shell and run this command (`node /home/parsecsv.js`) from the command line it works just fine. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

Check permission of the file, you may debug by giving full permission to file.

add this to your docker file and see if still the issue persists.

RUN chmod 777 /home/parsecsv.js

Comment: Ensure the file is executable with the following directive: `RUN chmod u+x /home/parsecsv.js`

Comment: @ИгорьБыстревский could you please share the Dockerfiles and sh file of cron in the question. That will help to look deeper.

Comment: @Prabhu i've posted an answer, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

So, what helped me is to copy js file to `/root` directory instead of `/home`. And then change path in work.sh to this: `node parsecsv.js` It seems like when node is running from sh script it cannot read absolute path or something. That's confusing, but now it is working.